# Why does the request take time when served by service worker from cache?

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I am using angular service worker. It is working fine and caching the static contents as I have mentioned in `ngsw-config.json`. However, when I look in network tab of Chrome, the static file i.e the javascript bundles which are stored by service worker take time to be downloaded. I am expecting it to be served quickly since it has to provide the data from cache but the response time is almost similar to the time it would take for actual request. So, is it a common feature or am I missing something here?

Here the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ServiceWorker should have refetched the contents of the scripts again to cache it. The ServiceWorker lifecycle may give a clue or more understanding in your case.

More information on lifecycle - https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#update_on_reload

Comment: Ok is there a way to stop this? Because there is no point in refetching the same file if the hash is not changed